# Generate android AOSP GPL package

Tags: android, android-source

Within AOSP, I can find the file `build/core/tasks/collect_gpl_sources.mk`.

Apparently it is used to create a archive of all GPL sources for redistribution.

How may I run the target within that makefile and generate the archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `make gpl_source_tgz` will create the archive.

The resulting archive will be at `${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/out/host/common/obj/PACKAGING/gpl_source_intermediates/gpl_sources.tgz`.

Comment: Sometimes, the obvious solution helps. Thanks.